# Clicking all the buttons containing "Follow"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following code

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('profile-badge__follow pull-right'); 

for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) {
  inputs[i].click();
}
```

to click all the buttons `<a class="profile-badge__follow pull-right" href="#">Follow</a>`

But this code also clicks all the buttons `<a class="profile-badge__follow profile-badge__follow--following pull-right" href="#">Unfollow</a>`

How do I only click the "Follow" buttons?

Comment: Can you give the `follow` buttons a class that the `unfollow` buttons don't have?

Comment: Why do you have the jquery tag but you're using plain Javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the inner html contains `Follow`

```
for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) 
{
    if(inputs[i].innerHTML.indexOf('Follow') > -1) {
        inputs[i].click(); 
    } 
}
```

Or if you want to it to be more specific

```
for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) 
{
    if(inputs[i].innerHTML == 'Follow') {
        inputs[i].click(); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using jQuery you could do it like :

```
$('.profile-badge__follow:contains("Follow")').click();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You don't need to use `.each()`, just call `.click()` on the collection.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `querySelectorAll()` to exclude the buttons with class `profile-badge__follow--following`;

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".profile-badge__follow.pull-right:not(.profile-badge__follow--following)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through each element . you might consider of using the concept of event bubbling here

check this snippet

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
container.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.nodeName == "A") {
    click.call(event.target);
  }
})


function click() {
  alert(this.innerHTML)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  ti<a class="profile-badge__follow pull-right" href="#">Follow</a>
  <a class="profile-badge__follow profile-badge__follow--following pull-right" href="#">Unfollow</a>
</div>
```

Hope it helps